# Add ID tag to parent <p>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this plugin which automatically creates input fields, wrapped in `<p>` elements. I need get those `<p>` elements for some other codes but they don't have an id.

The html is as follows and I wrote this code to add an id to the parent element. But it isn't working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.werkgever").parent().attr('id', 'hide_on_call');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="form_1651_field_13">Naam club of werkgever</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="form_1651_field_13" id="form_1651_field_13" value="" label="Naam club of werkgever" class="input werkgever" style="width: 100%">
</p>
```

Comment: I can see the ID added to the element in the DOM when I run that code.

Comment: Are the input fields created after the page was displayed? Maybe the `$(document).ready()` is ran before the input is created.

Comment: If you have multiple p>input (as implied by "creates input fields") then adding a *single* ID to *all* the `p` tags won't help you.   `$("#hide_on_call")` will only find the first one.   Do the same, but add a class.  Note that if you can select wrapper `p` with `$("input").closest("p")` then you don't need to add anything (id or class) to that `p` as you can reference it the same way in future, eg `$("#form_1651_field_13").closest("p").hide()`.  Seems like an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but I would use closest in case you decide to wrap the label around the input

```js
$(function() {
  $("input.werkgever").closest("p").attr('id', 'hide_on_call');
  console.log($("#hide_on_call").text()); // test it worked
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="form_1651_field_13">Naam club of werkgever</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="form_1651_field_13" id="form_1651_field_13" value="" label="Naam club of werkgever" class="input werkgever" style="width: 100%">
</p>
```

or just use `$("input.werkgever").closest("p").hide()` when you want to hide it